# I am trying to use SpinKit package in flutter but the spin loader don't show up

Tags: flutter, package, hybrid-mobile-app, flutter-dependencies, mobile-application

I have used Spinkit package to just enhance the user experience but I am not able to see the effect.

Under dependencies

```
flutter_spinkit: ^4.1.2+1
```

New dart file Loading.dart

```
    return Container(
      color: Colors.brown[100],
      child: Center(
        child: SpinKitChasingDots(
          color: Colors.brown,
          size: 50.0,
        ),
```

SingIn.dart file where I want to use spinkit

Here I am want to show spinkit loader is the load is true else scaffold

```
  bool load = false;

 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return load ? Loading() : Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Sign In") ,
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton.icon(onPressed: (){ widget.toggleView();}, icon: Icon(Icons.person), label: Text("Register"))
        ],
      ),
```

Here I want to show spin loader when app checks for validation and if validates successfully it shows the loader in the time it redirects to the next page

```
                if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
                  load = true;
                  dynamic result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.trim(), password);
                  if(result == null){
                    setState(() {
                      error = 'Please enter a valid email';
                      load = false;
                    }                      
                    );
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put load = true under setState()

```
    if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
                      setState((){
                  load = true;                             
                   })
                      
                      dynamic result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.trim(), password);
                      if(result == null){
                        setState(() {
                          error = 'Please enter a valid email';
                          load = false;
                        }                      
                        );
                      }
```